# Aggregated sub query for a join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to compare the values of 2 tables to make sure they match. In one table some rows are split into smaller rows so these need to be grouped before they can be joined with their equal match in the other table. I know this isn't the best design but it is what i have been given.

This is my current logic

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table2 T2
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT 
         MIN(No1) AS [No1],
         MIN(No2) AS [No2],
         SUM(Amount) AS [Amount]
     FROM 
         Table1
     GROUP BY 
         No1) T1 ON T1.No1 = T2.No1 AND T1.No2 = T2.No2
```

The result:

```
| No1 | No2 | Amount |    No1 |    No2 | Amount |
+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 111 | 222 |     20 |    111 |    222 |     20 |
| 222 | 444 |     50 |    222 |    444 |     50 |
| 333 | 222 |     10 |    333 |    222 |     30 |
| 333 | 444 |     20 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

I don't understand how the amount for 333-222 on the right side is 30 when I would expect it to be 10. What am I missing here? Thanks

SQL FIDDLE - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e6e4c/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to group by both the columns: `GROUP BY No1, No2`

Answer (score 2):

I don't get your confusion.  You have in `table1`:

```
('333', '222' , 10),
('333', '444' , 20);
```

When aggregated by `col1`, the sum is "30".  That is the "30" in the result set.

Perhaps you intend for the subquery to aggregate by both `col1` and `col2`.